# What is the purpose of the attribute srclang of the element track?

Tags: html

As the title says, my question is what is the purpose of the attribute srclang of the element track? I don't see any visual difference in the caption options when I include it. Also, I checked if this attribute has something to do with accessibility but the screen reader is announcing the caption options the same way like if we didn't have this attribute. Here's what MDN says about it:

> Language of the track text data. It must be a valid BCP 47 language
> tag. If the kind attribute is set to subtitles, then srclang must be
> defined.

But doesn't give any hints on what it actually does.

I checked the HTML specs as well and didn't find its use case being mentioned there.

Here's the example if it even matters:

```
<video
  poster="./images/image-width=1120.webp"
  width="500"
  height="500"
  controls
>
  <source type="video/mp4" src="./Dark_Haired_Girl_in_disbelief_1.mp4" />
  <track
    label="English"
    kind="subtitles"
    srclang="en"
    lang="en-US"
    src="./track-en.vtt"
  />
  <track
    label="French"
    kind="subtitles"
    srclang="fr"
    lang="fr-FR"
    src="./track-fr.vtt"
  />
  <p>Your browser doesn't support videos.</p>
</video>
```

What's the purpose of this attribute? Maybe it has something to do with SEO? Or it's just useless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is so the browser can autoselect the right subtitle track depending on the user's preferences. The `lang` attribute specifies the language of the label, so you can have e.g. `lang="nl" srclang="en"` to indicate a Dutch label for English subtitles.